# Event handling from Dialog box

Tags: android

I am creating a dialog box on a button click. For this I have created a class that extends Dialog. I created a XML file which contains the options (all are text view [7 text view]) in this XML file for each text view I have defined a tag android:onClick="imageProcessingHandler". When I click on the button from an activity it opens a Dialog box that is fine. Now when I click on any textview I am getting an error i.e. function not defined. I defined this function in the class as public that extends Dialog. Can anyone please help?

One more thing if I want to access Imageview; in the class that extends Dialog, of the activity from which Dialog box was opened so how could I do this?
I am trying to do the following:
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullphoto); but in this case imgView contains null value :(

Code:

From activity "MyActivity" on button click I am creating an object as:

```
ShowOptionsInDialog displayDialog = new ShowOptionsInDialog(this, passedData);
displayDialog.show();
```

ShowOptionsInDialog Class:

```
public class ShowOptionsInDialog extends Dialog{

private Context context;

public ShowOptionsInDialog(Context context, ArrayList<String> data) {
    super(context);
    this.context = (Context) context;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.imageprocessingoptions);
    setTitle("Try options");
}

public void imageProcessingHandler(View view){
ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullphoto);
}
```

imageprocessingoptions.XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/invertColorText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Invert Color"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="imageProcessingHandler" />
```

Activity code:

```
public class PhotoHandler extends Activity {
private Bundle intentExtra;
private String photoID;

private CommomObject _commonObject;
private Facebook facebook;

private ImageView photo;
private DownloadImageTask downlaodImageTask;

private ProgressDialog progDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photohandler);

    intentExtra = getIntent().getExtras();
    photoID = intentExtra.getString("PHOTO_ID");

    displayPhoto();
}

private void displayPhoto() {
    _commonObject = CommomObject.getInstance();
    facebook = _commonObject.getFacebookInstance();
    String imageURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+photoID+"/picture?type=normal&access_token="+facebook.getAccessToken();
    photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullphoto);
    photo.setTag(imageURL);
    photo.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    downlaodImageTask = new DownloadImageTask();
    progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progDialog.setMessage("Fetching photo...");
    progDialog.show();
    downlaodImageTask.execute(photo);
}

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap>{
    ImageView imageView = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews){
        this.imageView = imageViews[0];
        return downloadImage((String)imageView.getTag());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {

        Bitmap photo = null;

        try {

            URL u = new URL(url);
            URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
            c.connect();
            BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(c.getInputStream());
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            stream.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("PhotoHandler", "malformed url: " + url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PhotoHandler", "An error has occurred downloading the image: " + url);
        }
        progDialog.dismiss();
        return photo;
    }
}

public void footerHandler(View view){
    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.useButton:
        break;
    case R.id.saveButton:
        break;
    case R.id.shareButton:
        break;
    case R.id.photoEffect:
        ArrayList<String> passedData = new ArrayList<String>();
        ShowOptionsInDialog displayDialog = new ShowOptionsInDialog(this, passedData);
        displayDialog.show();
        break;
    }
}

public void imageProcessingHandler(View view){
    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.invertColorText:
        Bitmap newBitmap = ImageProcessing.doInvert(photo.getDrawingCache());
        photo.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
        break;
    case R.id.greyScaleText:
        break;
    case R.id.gammaCorrectionText:
        break;
    case R.id.sepiaEffectText:
        break;
    case R.id.embossingEffectText:
        break;
    case R.id.reflectionEffectText:
        break;
    case R.id.contrastText:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implement onCliclk listener in my code as:

```
TextView invert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.invertColorText);
invert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 // do your work here
});
```

and for getting ImageView on Dialog I passed it in Dailog from activity.

Answer (score 0):

1 - You need to put your `public void abcFunction(View view)` at your Dialog class.

2 - use `yourdialog.findViewById(R.id.fullphoto);`

Comment: Sorry but how could I implement 2nd one I think its not possible. And for 1st I also tried it.

Comment: Well your ImageView is null because it is only instantiated on the method, and if the method doesn't work, the image will contain null.

Comment: By the way, is the ImageView from the dialog xml? If not, try `context.findViewById(R.id.yourimageview)`

Comment: No ImageView is from Activity and above code is not correct I am getting error: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Context

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal Try putting `PhotoHandler.this` instead of only `this`. If this doesn't work it might have something to do with ASyncTask.